# How does the code that prints array elements works?

Tags: c

This code prints the array elements, but I can't understand how does k[x-1] gives the array elements.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
    int x[]={2,4,6,8,10},k=1;
    while (k<=5)
    {
    printf ("%3d",k[x-1]); 
    k++;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `k[x - 1]` is the same as `*(k + (x - 1))` is the same as `*(k + x - 1)` is the same as `*(x + k - 1)` ... `*(x + (k - 1))` ... `x[k - 1]`. The author of the code either made a typo (that worked well enough anyway), was experimenting, is a fan of Yoda, or was trying to beffudle the next programmer using his code...

Comment: I believe this code contains a typo. The line k[x-1] should be x[k-1].

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes start at 0 in C. An array like `int x[]={2,4,6,8,10}` will have a value `x[0]=2` and so forth. Typically, when iterating through an array, a convention like this is used:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    printf("%3d",x[i]);
```

Since the code you provided begins the indexing at 1, you have to subtract one to fetch the proper element.

Comment: I think he meant why the array name and index are switched like @pmg explained in his comment